# Displaying AMCharts inside an HTML table cell

Tags: html, html-table, amcharts

I am trying to display AMCharts inside an HTML table cell. I'm looping through data and creating a chart for each data item. Here is my HTML code:

```
<table id="theTable" class="display table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Number of Employees</th>
                <th>Number of Volunteers</th>
                <th>Chart</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>IT</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td><div id="chart_1"></div></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>HR</td>
                    <td>35</td>
                    <td>14</td>
                    <td><div id="chart_2"></div></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>LG</td>
                    <td>100</td>
                    <td>65</td>
                    <td><div id="chart_3"></div></td>
                 </tr>
                </tbody>

                </table>
```

And here is my Javascript code:

```
var emp = [30, 35, 100];
var vol = [5, 14, 65];
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  var str = "chart_" + j.toString();
  var chart = AmCharts.makeChart(str, {
      "type": "pie",
      "dataProvider": [{
               "type": "Employees",
               "per": parseFloat(emp[j]),
               "color": "#54e83a"
               }, {
               "type": "Volunteers",
               "per": parseFloat(vol[j]),
               "color": "#41ba2c"
             }],
               "valueField": "per",
               "titleField": "type",
               "colorField": "color",
               "balloon": {
               "fixedPosition": true
               },
               "export": {
               "enabled": true
               },
               "startDuration": 0
               });
   }
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated! Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c3at2kbj/4/)

(Please ignore this text the Editor is saying my post is mostly code so I'm adding non-code text hoping to trick it...This is unprofessional I know.)

Answer (score 0):

AmChart divs must have dimensions specified through CSS, otherwise they won't display. Set the sizes and you're all set, for example:

```
#chart_1, #chart_2, #chart_3 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

You also need to adjust your loop logic as you're starting from chart_0, when your divs are starting from chart_1. Either update your html or fix your string creation, e.g. `var str = "chart_" + (j + 1);` (note you don't need `toString()`)

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c3at2kbj/7/)